# How can I translate the validation messages of Struts 2?

Tags: localization, internationalization, struts2

I want to learn how to use Struts 2 and I created a simple application following a tutorial I found.

I've created a `<MyActionClass>-validation.xml` file and I wonder how can I translate the validation messages to multiple languages?

```
<field name="password">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <param name="trim">true</param>
        <message>You have to enter a password.</message> 
                 <!-- How can I localize this message? -->
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

Can I get the messages from a localized .properties file or do I have to use some other kind of validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found it out myself. You have to create a .properties file for the class, then you can change the code from:

```
<message>You have to enter a password.</message>
```

to:

```
<message key="[message key from the properties file]" />
```